# Determine if PSTN call was answered or went to voicemail

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am creating a report on Teams PSTN calls using the communications/callRecords/getPstnCalls endpoint. I was expecting to see a field specifying whether it was answered or if it was rejected or went to voicemail. I do not see anything to indicate this.

The goal is to provide support call statistics and whether or not the call was answered by a live agent is crucial information. Is there a way to determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to determine if PSTN call was answered or went to voicemail.

If you wish you can suggest this feature here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)